# How to make checkboxes behave like radio buttons in ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have faced problem to use Checkbox behave like radio button in ng-repeat. Where select and unselect the box and one time only one box will be selected. It is working **Without Ng-repeat.** But i want to use this in **ng-repeat.**

**Here is my HTML File :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
       <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
       <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.1.5"></script>
       <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <h1> WithOut ng-repeat </h1>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="model1=='11'" ng-click="model1='11'"> a
     <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="model1=='12'" ng-click="model1='12'"> b
     <br/>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="model1=='13'" ng-click="model1='13'"> c
     <br>
     Model = {{model1}}
  <h1> With ng-repeat </h1>
    <div data-ng-repeat="p in pp.rate">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="model=='{{p.price}}'"  
          ng-click="model='{{p.price}}'"> 
        Model = {{model}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is My Controller :**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pp = { 
      rate: [ {price: '11'},
              {price: '12'},
              {price: '13'}
      ]
     };
});
```

**Here is My Plunker Link**
   http://plnkr.co/edit/BUHPNjTGaIsG33hsSWeC?p=preview

**Please Give Me a solution** thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons. This is what they are for.

Comment: Because my requirement not a radio buttons that's why i am using checkbox.

Comment: Would quietly suggest that your requirements may benefit from being adjusted.  Designers rarely seem to know the difference between a radio button and a checkbox.

Comment: It is a valid requirement - user can select none or one of something.  With radio buttons you cannot deselect.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem today and I finally found a nice solution:

```html
<div data-ng-repeat="p in pp.rate">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="result.price" ng-true-value="{{p.price}}" ng-false-value="" > 
    {{p.plan}}
</div>
```

plunkr demo http://plnkr.co/edit/qLlFBhnUdzTnAu1U71uk?p=preview

I hope it helps you, or it helps others in the future

Have fun!

Comment: This doesnt works in angular 1.3.14. Maybe needs some editing.

Comment: Worked for me, if you dont mind would you tell me what is ng-true-value and ng-false-value doing

Comment: Usman Iqbal ng-false-value and ng-true-value are the values you want to use instead of false and true... so on this case to be true (checked) you need the price and to be false(unchecked) just an empty string

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with ng-repeat creating a new scope and you not using `dot` notation to reference your model.

See the updated plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/EQdv60ppdVm5Nkp2o8p8?p=preview

I added a object `selection` that tracks selection instead of a `model` string value. The checkbox is then checked against `selection.model` instead of `model`

Highly recommend you read https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
 to understand prototypal inheritance and the effect on scope.

Comment: Thanks for guide me but is your case if i  selected on checkbox then it show same value for all check box but my requiement is one select one time and show only value of selected one...Here is problem Occured Check this Link  http://plnkr.co/edit/Qb7VW7jDMCSfvHwvVvNR?p=preview

Comment: It does not show same value, but the same variable is updated for each check bos. See this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/iuAJavKmgy8neg9BkpBA?p=preview

Comment: hey thanks ChanderMani Actually i m using this in right way thanks to solve my problem ..

Comment: can you please tell me if checkbox is not selected then how to show 0 value of {{selection.model}}  .

Comment: Since it is a single select, `selection` will only contain what is selected\checked. What is not selected is implicitly 0.

Comment: Hello @Chandermani Can you please help me how to show value is 0 if checkbox is unselect .. Can you check this In Above Link that is given by you. Please help me./